# Sens de mêler dans « ils mêlaient l'absent » (Camus, La Peste) ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, usage, verbes

> Ils éprouvaient ainsi la souffrance profonde de tous les prisonniers
> et de tous les exilés, qui est de vivre avec une mémoire qui ne sert à
> rien. Ce passé même auquel ils réfléchissaient sans cesse n'avait que
> goût du regret. Ils auraient voulu, en effet, pouvoir lui ajouter tout
> ce qu'ils déploraient de n'avoir pas fait quand ils pouvaient encore
> le faire avec celui ou celle qu'ils attendaient - de même qu'à toutes
> les circonstances, même relativement heureuses, de leur vie de
> prisonniers, ils **mêlaient** l'absent, et ce qu'ils étaient alors ne
> pouvaient les satisfaire. (Camus, *La Peste*)

Je ne comprends pas le mot "mêlaient(mêler)". Est-ce qu'il désigne mélanger?

Answer (score 3):

*Mêler* signfie en ici "mettre dedans et mélanger". Le sens est peut-être peu clair par ce que le complément est introduit par "à" , et est placé avant le sujet. On peut reformuler la phrase comme suit:

> ils mêlaient l'absent (rem: signifie ici "la sensation d'absence") à toutes les circonstances, même relativement heureuses, de leur vie de prisonniers

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je le comprends maintenant.